# Laravel: Capture a difference between a Controller __construct()'s stage and other methods run stage

Tags: laravel

I am extending Laravel's controller for a package.

So I know Laravel controllers run their constructor and method at different stages of the app.

```
public function __construct()
{
    //Middlewares have not run yet
    //auth()->check() or auth()->user() do not work yet
}
```

And in any other method in your Controller

```
public function anyOtherMethod()
{
    //All good, everything has booted.
}
```

I am looking a way of distinguishing between the two stages. For example, is there a method that says?

```
app()->middlewaresHaveBeenHandled(); //returns true or false

//or 

app()->authIsBootedYouMayUseIt(); //returns true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

The `session` from the request is null if the latter wan't yet handled by the app. So a good check would be

```
if(request()->route() && !request()->hasSession()){
    //request has not been handled
}else{
    //request has been handled
}
```

The check for the request route is necessary to make sure it is an HTTP request and it won't interfere with Tests or Console actions